# Alternative to geom_linerange and facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to achieve a graph something like this using ggplot:

[image]

The closest I can get is:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, color = Rain)) + 
geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1)) +
facet_wrap(~Station, ncol = 1)
```

which gives:

[image]

I can sort out all the formatting details. My question is: can I achieve this with `Station` on the y-axis instead of as a facet variable, as in the original?

I don't think `geom_linerange` is the right way to go for this. I tried putting `Station` as the `y` aesthetic but that didn't work. Is there another geom I could use instead?

Comment: Good question.  It couldn't hurt to use `dput` to include your sample data in the question.

Comment: I would try `ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, y = Station, fill = factor(Rain)))` with `geom_tile()` or `geom_raster()`

Comment: @donlelek Thanks, exactly what I want! Both geoms seem to work. From the [documentation:](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html) **geom_raster is a high performance special case for when all the tiles are the same size** So geom_raster would be better to use here?

Comment: Glad it helped @Danny, I think `geom_raster` would be appropriate in this case. It is faster and allows you to control the positioning of the tiles which it seems only possible with this geom (i.e. `hjust` or `vjust`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented above, I think `geom_raster` would be your best option here. Let's make up some data to see how it works.

```
library(ggplot)
dat <- data.frame(Date    = c(1:5, 1:5), 
                  Station = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)), 
                  Rain    = c(0,0,1,1,0, NA,1,0,1,1))
```

A simple plot would be,

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Date, Station)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = factor(Rain)))
```

[image: plot1]

Now, the advantage of using `geom_raster` over `geom_tile` is that you can control the justification of the tile using `hjust` and `vjust`. Values for this go from 0 to 1, the default is 0.5, let's try replacing those for zeroes

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Date, Station)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = factor(Rain)),
              hjust = 0,
              vjust = 0)
```

[image]

I think the default option works fine, I hope this helps. 
Cheers!

Comment: This is perfect thanks! Just in case anyone else is doing similar, I also added: `+ geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0.5, by = 1, length.out = length(levels(dat$Station)) + 1))` to @donlelek's code to include separating lines between stations which look quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, color = Rain)) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1)) +
    facet_wrap(Station ~ .)
```

Use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid` puts the labels on the axis instead of cluttering up the whole grid by putting the labels on top of individual charts.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely an improvement! Although I do prefer the solution using geom_tile or geom_raster over this still since facet isn't needed at all for that.